# http://url call in start request in scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, request, scrapy

i am using scrapy to scrape the data from website

```
def start_requests(self):
    request = scrapy.Request(url="http://www.xxxxx.com",callback=self.parse ,dont_filter = True,)
    yield request
```

while requesting the url from start_requests i am getting 
error

```
raise SchemeNotSupported("Unsupported scheme: %r" % (uri.scheme,))
twisted.web.error.SchemeNotSupported: Unsupported scheme: b''
2018-06-11 13:02:26 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-06-11 13:02:26 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

but when calling the same request using the secured line i.e("https://www.xxxxx.com")
it is working
can anyone please help

Comment: directly adding the urls in the start_urls["http://www.XXXXXXX.com",] it is working but calling from start_requests it is throwing error

Comment: can't reproduce this. What version of twisted are you using?

Comment: i am using twisted Version('Twisted', 18, 4, 0)

Comment: twisted Version('Twisted', 18, 4, 0)

Comment: can you post the url which you want to scrape?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue, and for me the problem was protocol.

I was requesting using `http` while that should be `https`

When I changed it, that started working.